# How to use all available space vertically in a CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to build a web layout with a title bar, a nav header, a footer and a main content area in the middle (split in two for a sidebar and main view).

I intend to use CSS Grid layout for it. My current code manages it all, except: The main content (and sidebar) adjust to its content. And that's not what I want.

How can I make that 3rd grid row fill all remaining vertical space?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content auto min-content;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "nav nav" "sidebar main" "footer footer";
}

.title {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #1BC336;
}

.navigation {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #C3A21B;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #1BC3B9;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #5C1BC3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Title Bar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">Navbar</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar:<br>Info-type stuff about what's currently being shown in main</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Main content</h2><br>Should occupy all the remaining space. <br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution**

Set *grid height* to the *viewport height* - add `height: 100vh` to the `.grid` and reset the default browser `body` margin to zero.

---

**Why**

This is because unless the *container* (for which you have given `display: grid`) has a set `height`, it will take *only* as much space as its contents. *So when you give height there is available space now to fill into*. See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body { /* ADDED */
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content auto min-content;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "nav nav" "sidebar main" "footer footer";
  height: 100vh; /* ADDED */
}

.title {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #1BC336;
}

.navigation {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #C3A21B;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #1BC3B9;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #5C1BC3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Title Bar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">Navbar</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar:<br>Info-type stuff about what's currently being shown in main</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Main content</h2><br>Should occupy all the remaining space. <br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: An undeleted answer will appear with the date and time it was first posted? SO is weird sometimes ^^

Answer (score 6):

> How can I make that 3rd grid row fill all remaining vertical space?

In your layout, *there is no remaining vertical space*. Since your container doesn't have a defined height, its height is based on the height of the content. So there's no extra space to distribute.

However, if your container had, let's say, the height of the viewport...

```
.grid { height: 100vh }
```

... then you could get the sidebar and main content (collectively, the third row) to take all remaining height with:

```
.grid { grid-template-rows: min-content min-content 1fr min-content; }
```

instead of

```
.grid { grid-template-rows: min-content min-content auto min-content; }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content 1fr min-content;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" 
                        "nav nav" 
                        "sidebar main"
                        "footer footer";
}

.title {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #1BC336;
}

.navigation {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #C3A21B;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #1BC3B9;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #5C1BC3;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Title Bar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">Navbar</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar:
    <br>Info-type stuff about what's currently being shown in main</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  <div class="main">
    <h2>Main content</h2>
    <br>Should occupy all the remaining space.
</div>
</div>
```